# How to handle temporary unreachable online api

Tags: api, synchronization, offline, offline-caching

This is a more general question, so bear with my abstraction of the following problem.

I'm currently developing an application, that is interfacing with a remote server over a public api. The api in question does provide mechanisms for fetching data based on a timestamp (e.g. "get me everything that changed since xxx"). Since the amount of data is quite high, I keep a local copy in a database and check for changes on the remote side every hour.

While this makes the application robust against network problems (remote server in maintenance, network outage, etc.) and enables employees to continue working with the application, there is one big gaping problem:

The api in question also offers write access. E.g. my application can instruct the remote server to create a new object. Currently I'm sending the request via api, and upon success create the object in my local database, too. It will eventually propagate via the hourly data fetching, where my application (ideally) sees that no changes need to be made to the local database.

Now when the api is unreachable, i create the object in my database, and cache the request until the api is reachable again. This has multiple problems:

1. If the request fails (due to not beforehand validateble errors), I end up with an object in the database which shouldn't even exist. I could delete it, but it seems hard to explain to the user(s) ("something went wrong with the api, we deleted that object again").
2. The problem especially cascades when depended actions que up. E.g. creating the object, and two more requests for modifying it. When the initial create fails, so will the modifying requests (since the object does not exist on the remote side)
3. Worst case is deletion - when an object is deleted locally, but will not be deleted on the remote site, I have no way of restoring it (easily).

One might suggest to never create objects locally, and let them propagate only through the hourly data sync. This unfortunately is not an option. If the api is not accessible, it can be for hours. And it is mandatory that employees can continue working with the application (which they cannot when said objects don't exist locally).

So bottom line:
How to handle such a scenario, where the api might not be reachable, but certain requests must be cached locally and repeated when the api is reachable again. Especially how to handle cases where those requests unpredictable fail.